# Redux Toolkit dispatch inside createAsyncThunk calls causes rendering twice (React Native)

Tags: redux-toolkit

I found this problem in all my applications. I create an action and call this action inside createAsyncThunk and see twice rendering.

I have been using redux and had no such problems, but when I switched to Redux Toolkit, problems arose. I created this example for you, using only the redux toolkit, the initial application shell. A small application is not difficult to look at the code.

```
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.19.3",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.9",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.8",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.14",
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.7",
"axios": "^1.5.1",
"lodash": "^4.17.21",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.72.5",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.13.1",
"react-native-indicators": "^0.17.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "^3.5.4",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.2",
"react-native-screens": "^3.25.0",
"react-native-svg": "^13.14.0",
"react-redux": "^8.1.3",
"redux-persist": "^6.0.0"
```

It doesn't matter whether the persister is connected or not, the behavior is the same!

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/3783#issuecomment-1752336687

Comment: We can't address issues in code we can't see. Please do [edit] the post to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with and include details on what the actual issue is, including reproduction steps.

Answer (score 0):

No need to create deleteFavorite action, try dispatch changeDriversInfo with delay:

```
const onButtonPressed = (payload) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    dispatch(changeDriversInfo({ key: 'value', value: payload }));
  }, 2000);
};
```

Replace your delay from async action and try to remove "finally" part, example of action:

```
export const deleteFavorite = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/deleteFavorite',
  async (payload: string, { dispatch, rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
       await exampleService.something();
    } catch (e) {
      rejectWithValue(e);
    } 
  },
);
```